# Qt replace string between two string

Tags: string, qt

I need to find the string between two string and replace it with a new string.

Here is the input string

```
QMainWindow#MainWindow{background-image: url(./Flocking_by_noombox.jpg);}
```

I need to identify the image name `./Flocking_by_noombox.jpg` and replace with the new name without knowing what text inside  `url()`

I think first I have to find the string between `QMainWindow#MainWindow{background-image: url(` and `);}` and replace it with new name.

How it's possible in Qt.

Comment: Use [QString::replace method](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#replace)

Comment: I cannot use replace as the value inside url() can be any value.

Comment: You can use a regular expression with `QString::replace(const QRegularExpression &re)`, but in your case you could do a simple approach and just look for the index of the `url(` and closing bracket `)` and replace everything in between!?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty solution, as @xander sugessted:

```
QString s = "QMainWindow#MainWindow{background-image: url(./Flocking_by_noombox.jpg);}";
int index = s.indexOf("url");
QString name = "someName";
QString after = "url(" + name + ");}";
QString replaced = s.mid(0,index) + after;
```